# Segmentation fault in Binary Search in C

Tags: c, binary-search

I'm trying to write a program that scans an input file that contains the number of letters in the array, a sorted list of letters, the number of letters to search for, a list of letters to search for. It displays the search results in a format shown in the sample file.

I'm getting a segmentation fault error message at runtime with the code I have included below. Now before this post gets negative feedback for not including the right amount of code, I don't really know where the error is with this segmentation fault. I've included the relevant files here on Pastebin:

#### [main.c](http://pastebin.com/aXR8g1kH)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Proto.h"

int main()
{
    /* Accepts number of elements from user */
    scanf("%d", &elements);

    /* Creates dynamic array */
    array = (char *) calloc(elements, sizeof(char));

    /* Copies sorted values to the dynamic array */
    for(i = 0; i < elements; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", &array[i]);
    }

    /* Accepts number of elements to search */
    scanf("%d", &search);

    /* Searches for elements in sorted array one at a time */
    for(i = 1; i <= search; i++)
    {
        /* Accepts value to search */
        scanf("%s", &value);

        /* Resets counter to 0 */
        count = 0;

        /* Finds location of element in the sorted list using binary search */
        location = binarySearch(array, value, 0, (elements-1));

        /* Checks if element is present in the sorted list */
        if (location == -1)
        {
            printf("%4s not found!\n", value);
        }

        else
        {
            printf("%4s found at %4d iteration during iteration %4d\n", value, location, count);
        }
    }
    free(array);
}
```

#### [BinarySearch.c](http://pastebin.com/THKGAzi8)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Proto.h"

int binarySearch(char * nums, char svalue, int start, int end)
{
    middle = (start + end) / 2;

    /* Target found */
    if (nums[middle] == svalue)
    {
        return middle;
    }

    /* Target not in list */
    else if( start == end )
    {
        return -1;
    }

    /* Search to the left */
    else if( nums[middle] > svalue )
    {
        count++;
        return binarySearch( nums, svalue, start, (middle-1) );
    }

    /* Search to the right */
    else if( nums[middle] < svalue )
    {
        count++;
        return binarySearch( nums, svalue, (middle+1), end );
    }
}
```

#### [Proto.h](http://pastebin.com/iEpn1wLP)

```
#ifndef _PROTO_H
#define _PROTO_H

char * array;
int elements, search, location, count, middle, i;
char value;
int binarySearch(char *, char, int, int);

#endif
```

#### [Sample Input/Output](http://pastebin.com/i2nWjwnZ)

```
Sample Input file:
6
a d n o x y
3
n x z

Sample Output file:
  n found at    2 during iteration    0. 
  x found at    4 during iteration    1.
  z not found!
```

Comment: Include the code in your question. Further, what have you tried? Got a debugger?

Comment: You need to put the code in the question. Failing to do so leads to downvotes. But put the right amount. That is just enough to demonstrate the fault, and no more: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Don't put variables in headers — the only item in the header should be the function prototype.  You shouldn't have that many global variables for a binary search function (you only need zero — one if you instrument with the counter).  `middle` should be a local variable in the binary search code; the others should be local variables in `main()`.  Avoid global variables as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not check the whole code but I see this error inyour `main.c`

your code

```
    /* Creates dynamic array */
    array = (char *) calloc(elements, sizeof(char));

    /* Copies sorted values to the dynamic array */
    for(i = 0; i < elements; i++)
    {
            scanf("%s", &array[i]);
    }
```

is wrong. your `array` shoud be double pointer `char **array`

```
    /* Creates dynamic array */
    array = calloc(elements, sizeof(char*));

    /* Copies sorted values to the dynamic array */
    for(i = 0; i < elements; i++)
    {
            scanf("%ms", &array[i]);
    }
```

Try to divide your code and found out the part wich is the cause of the problem and back a gain with a small part of code this will help to find out the solution